# Prove $ \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} = 2^n$ using binomial expansion? Right or wrong?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am in a probability and statistics class.  This is one of the first proofs we are supposed to do I am not sure where to start.  I have done some research and I have seen proof by induction for problems like this and also Pascal's Triangle.  I am just not sure if there is a specific way I should be proving this is my specific course.  We have covered basic probability and this problem comes from a section on an introduction to discrete random variables.

Prove $$ \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} = 2^n$$

Here is how I would start:
$2^n = (1 +1)^n = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}1^01^{n-0}$ 
using the binomial expansion... is this the right way to start? or am I totally off? I would appreciate a very basic explanation of this!

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly fine, but the sum should be $\sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x} 1^x 1^{n-x}$.

Comment: okay so that summation would simplify to $ n \choose x$ $1^n$  so 1 to any power is 1 so it simplifies to just $ n \choose x$

Answer (score 1):

You're close:

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$$

If you put $x=1$ in this you get $$(1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^k$$

i.e.
$$2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 1):

One way is
$$
(1+t)^n = \sum_{x=0}^n {n \choose x} t^n
$$
and let $t = 1$.

Another way is to simply note that you are counting all subsets of a set of size n, and there are clearly 2^n of those since each subset is uniquely formed by making one of 2 choices for each element (inclusion or exclusion in the set).

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track.

Now, $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk 1^k1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk.$$

Comment: I think I might have been trying to make this a little more complicated then I needed to

Comment: I've found that's a tendency that many people have when learning something new.

Comment: I have a similar problem $ \sum_{x=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^x = 0 $ which I tried to simplify as $0 = (1 + (-1))^n$ which by binomial expansion is  $ \sum_{x=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^x(-1)^{n-x}$... I am stuck here. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is the right idea.

Comment: How do I simplify it to get to just $(-1)^x$